# Changed one 1 GB SODIMM (of two) for a 2 GB one, but my EB1501U still only sees 2 GB

Tags: windows-7, memory, eee-pc, eeebox, sodimm

Changed one 1 GB SODIMM (of two) for a 2 GB one, but my Asus EeeBox EB1501U still only sees 2 GB.

The computer is running Win7 x86 (from factory).

The specs says "max 4 GB".

How can one get the EB1501U to recognize all memory (i.e. 3 GB)?

UPDATE:
I'm looking at the system in the BIOS right now, and it says 
"Installed Size: 3072MB
 Usable Size: 2560MB".

I.e. the added memory is recognized there, and there's nothing with the hardware that hides the smaller SODIMM module.

(The EB1501 has NVIDIA ION, hence the diff.)

Comment: As a side note reminder, 32bit versions of Windows can only use up to ~4GB of RAM. See SU question here: http://superuser.com/questions/67444/is-there-way-to-enable-4gb-ram-in-32-bit-windows-os/67596#67596 (you are only using 3GB so you should be fine, but please do be aware of the limitations in specific Windows versions.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

... and after (yet another!) restart Win7 sees the whole 3GB :-)

Comment: Hooray! I'm guessing probably just static.

Answer (score 1):

Lacking exact specs on the DIMMs, is it possible there is a conflict in, say, clock speed or something that's causing the 1GB stick to not be recognized with the 2?  If you put the original stick back in do you still have 2GB (aka, are you sure that stick is good?)

It's also possible that your board requires the larger stick to be in a certain slot; it's very unusual but I have seen it.

Comment: I've updated my question with BIOS info, and the whole 3GB is visible there.